# React Native Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module

Tags: reactjs, native

I am having issues with a shared github project our team is working on. I have been banging my head against this issue for about a week now without any luck.

The issue is a brand new clone that is working on my teams computers, will not run correctly on my computer. It throws the error, "Module AppRegistry is not a callable module". I am working on a ios project. I have deleted all folders and started again. I have created new users with various permissions and no luck.

Is there anything else that I am missing to try? Thanks!

---

Index.ios.js

```
const { AppRegistry } = require('react-native');
const setup = require('./app/setup');

AppRegistry.registerComponent('mobileapps', setup);
```

Setup.js

```
import App from './index';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store';

const store = configureStore();

function setup() {
  class Root extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
  }

  return Root;
}

module.exports = setup;
```

Comment: Did you double check your dependencies and versions?

Comment: also check your exports statement in your index.ios.js and your imports

Comment: Yes I have. I also just found out, that when I create a new project, as in like I run "react-native init newProject", I get the same error now.

Comment: post your index.ios.js code

Comment: Any reason why you're using a factory to define a class and return it?

Comment: Might not be the actual issue, but here you're using es6 imports at the same time as commonJS exports.

Answer (score 4):

Okay I figured it out after doing a new react-native init and installing each of my npm packages individually to see which one breaks. I found out it was RNCookies manager but the entire issue was I needed to run a `rnpm link`.